# AWS RDS datapump directory to be used

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, datapump, impdp, expdp

I know nothing much about aws. Could you help to resolve the issue.

I need to take a dump of my Database in AWS Oracle RDS, so trying a command which is shown below

expdp ***/****@WINDMIG5 schemas=agTransform directory=/rdsdbdata/datapump dumpfile=TransformData.dmp logfile=TransformData.log

But it says directory not found,  not sure,where to check this directory, to find if it exists.
Querying the dba_directories, I can find this as below.

DATA_PUMP_DIR   /rdsdbdata/datapump

Can anyone please help to figure this out, on what is wrong, why directory is not found, and where this directory is located and if there is any issue in the command.
I used exp command and it is still running for two days to get the dump.(35 GB data)

Thank you for the help.
Manju

Answer (score 0):

The `direcotry` parameter is a logical name stored in the database, with reference to an actual directory on the database server storage.

This [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-EEB32B50-8A00-40B0-8787-CC2C8BA05DC5.htm#SUTIL819) explains this well.

> Because Data Pump is server-based rather than client-based, dump
>   files, log files, and SQL files are accessed relative to server-based
>   directory paths. Data Pump requires that directory paths be specified
>   as directory objects. A directory object maps a name to a directory
>   path on the file system. DBAs must ensure that only approved users are
>   allowed access to the directory object associated with the directory
>   path.
>
> The following example shows a SQL statement that creates a directory
>   object named dpump_dir1 that is mapped to a directory located at
>   /usr/apps/datafiles.
>
> ```
> SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir1 AS '/usr/apps/datafiles';
> ```